# Is there any way to display numerous output neatly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have numerous number of outputs and I want them to show as follow

Friction factor  = xxx

Load factor      = xxx

Thermal factor   = xxxx

Is there any way to make the equal sign '=' align to each other? I've tried using the 'fprintf' function with '\t'. However, it's tough for me to achieve such arrangement.

Sincerely thank you for all the helps.

Comment: By "display" you mean as a text in the command line, as a graphic as in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5752-guisheet-java-gui-table-from-matlab, or just as saving to txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
disp(['Friction factor = ' num2str(xxx)])
disp(['Load factor     = ' num2str(yyy)])
disp(['Thermal factor  = ' num2str(zzz)])
```

Comment: Ya..I think this will be the way...but I have lots of outputs so I'm seeking is there any other more convenient way..anyway thank you so much ya @natan

Comment: How are the text titles for tje outputs saved (i.e. Load Factor etc...)? If they are in a cell array or something like that this can be automated quite easily...

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
names = {'Friction Factor','Load Factor','Thermal Factor'};
values = [xx,yy,zz];

nameLength = cellfun(@numel,names);

format = sprintf('%%-%is = %%f\\n',max(nameLength));

for n = 1:length(names)
    fprintf(format,names{n},values(n));
end
```

Comment: +1 for the automated version... the title outputs though look like they are aligned to the right.